# Openni compilation error

Tags: openni, eigen

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting a compilation error when building openni on Ubuntu 10.10:

In file included from openni_camera/src/openni_driver.cpp:43:
openni_camera/include/openni_camera/openni.h:45: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory

I'm using the version checked out from git https://github.com/ros-pkg-git/ni.git with an svn installation of ROS.  Presumably there's some library that I'm missing.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9160/openni-compilation-error/) by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on ROS Answers with karma: 995 on 2011-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The solution I found was to install the diamondback version of ROS.

http://www.ros.org/wiki/diamondback/

Only then could I get openni to compile as per the instructions.

---

Originally posted by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) with karma: 995 on 2011-02-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are missing the Eigen package.  There are instructions on how to install openni on the [ni wiki page](http://ros.org/wiki/ni)

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-02-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JediHamster](https://answers.ros.org/users/146/jedihamster/) on 2011-02-22**:
I've followed the instructions, but still end up with the same compile error.  Do I need to install Eigen separately?